# The confused meaning of sentences from google

Tags: meaning

I found three strange sentences in Google.

Please explain their meanings to me.

> 1.I fancy fancy cheeses.
>
> 2.I do do it.
>
> 3.I'll be in 20 minutes.

Comment: do you mean I'll be in **in** 20 minutes? Is it the doubling of certain words that is confusing you?

Answer (score 3):

"fancy" is both a verb and an adjective.

> I like artisanal cheeses.
>   I fancy fancy cheeses.

"do" is both a so-called "light" verb and a verb of normal weight.

> I do indeed engage in that activity.
>   I do do it.

"in" can mean "inside, indoors" and "within a specified time-window", depending on whether it is alone or has a temporal complement:

> I will be indoors within 20 minutes.
>   I will be in in 20 minutes.

These words, which look identical on the page, are given different intonations and phrasings in *spoken* English which distinguish them from one another according to their grammatical roles.

Learning a language from  words on a page is far more difficult than learning a language from native *speakers* of the language *as they are speaking it*. The written word is a crude approximation of speech.